# perl script for history file in .bash_profile appending to the history command

Tags: bash, perl

I have .bash_profile setup to export to a history file:

```
export HISTFILE=/root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print $1}')
```

Then I am exporting time stamps for the history command.

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y/%m/%d %T "
```

This combination caused epoch time stamps to be written to the history file:

```
#1463962023
top
```

So I wrote in a perl one liner into the .bash_profile to only write in the human readable time stamp into the file thus eliminating the epoch line: ( and a few other lines)

```
format_history () {
local file=/root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print $1}')
perl -i -pe 's/^#(\d{10})$/"# ".localtime($1)/e' "$file"
}

shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;format_history;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

So now my exported file looks like this:

```
# Sun May 22 19:06:41 2016
last
```

Which is great and exactly what I want. However, this has the unwanted side effect of appending a dedicated line in the history command which contains nothing but dates that does not need to be there.

```
 824  2016/05/22 19:07:33 # Sun May 22 19:06:41 2016
 825  2016/05/22 19:07:33 last
```

How can I write to the file like I want without causing the history command to report these unwanted lines?

NOTE - This anomoly with the history command seems to be "activated" when I log in to a system. ( I use ssh) I can be in session, run 10 commands, then run the history command and all looks normal. However as soon as a log out and log back in and run the history command, it will display the erroneous lines.

UPDATE: I have narrowed down the problem to the line:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;format_history;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

When I comment out this line the history command works as expected. However, this was also the command that ran the formatting on the history file. I have tried to remove the "history -a" part from the line, leaving the rest, but that does not make any difference. If I were to leave the whole line commented out, how could I invoke the formatting on the file using the perl script?

Answer (score 2):

I created a similar function (some time ago) which does what you're wanting I think:

```
# export detailed history
exphtd () { HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T ' history | grep -v "^#" > /root/history/.bash_hist ; }
```

Then to use:

```
$ exphtd
```

**Output:**

```
455  2016-05-20 15:12:46 cd ~
```

Comment: It's unclear if it is or isn't what you want; exporting bash history without the [num] though seems a bit useless.

Comment: I will look into your suggestion. However I'd like to get this to work using the perl script. I have narrowed the problem down to "PROMPT_COMMAND" line, however when I comment that out in .bash_profile the formatting does not run on the file.

Comment: I am trying your suggestion however when you say "Then to use" run exphtd do you do that one time at the command line after your source the file or will you have to do that each time you log in?

Comment: I think the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` at the end of `history -a;format_history;$PROMPT_COMMAND` might be causing your issue; try removing it (sorry I'm not able to test it atm, since I'm not around my machine). If the perl line in your function is just converting the date you could simply do `HISTTIMEFORMAT='%c '`  instead, as it should convert  time/date to "national representation" format.

Comment: Regarding your question about "then to use"; `exphtd` calls the function (like your `format_history`, I just have it named something else). I'm still not entirely clear on what the exact format you want actually is.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it works, but not without some quirks. First of all, I have to use the absolute path and filename in the redirect, It does not work when I use the "who -m" variable. Second, each time I log out and log back in the history from the last session gets re-apppended over the existing and I get duplicates on each line. Each login/logout appends another timestamp to the same line. Third, if one was to issue a history -c, it would wipe out the history file as well.

Comment: I don't recall mentioning history -c. The way I use my example is by placing the function in ~/.bash_profile; I've never had any of the issues you explained. Whenever I want to get the formatted bash_history I just use "exphtd" at the prompt and my file gets generated.

Comment: Ah..I was putting that into the "PROMPT COMMAND" statement. I will give it another go.